# Grit: Find blob by ID

Tags: ruby, grit

Is there any way that I can get a blob by id using Grit? I know I can do this:

```
@repo.tree/"myfile.txt"
```

But is there any way I can get a blob from the tree by its id?

EDIT:

Solution was this:
https://github.com/mojombo/grit/issues/#issue/12

Comment: You may want to consider answering your own question, so this gets removed from the unanswered list. Thanks!